# Conditional replacement using dplyr's mutate_all

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
mytbl <- tibble(a = rep(c(1,1,0,1), 4), b= rep(c(1,0,0,1), 4))

    # A tibble: 16 × 2
           a     b
       <dbl> <dbl>
    1      1     1
    2      1     0
    3      0     0
    4      1     1
    5      1     1
    6      1     0
    7      0     0
    8      1     1
    9      1     1
    10     1     0
    11     0     0
    12     1     1
    13     1     1
    14     1     0
    15     0     0
    16     1     1
```

If I condition on the second column all is well

```
dplyr::mutate_all(mytbl, funs(replace(., b != 0, NA)))

    # A tibble: 16 × 2
           a     b
       <dbl> <dbl>
    1     NA    NA
    2      1     0
    3      0     0
    4     NA    NA
    5     NA    NA
    6      1     0
    7      0     0
    8     NA    NA
    9     NA    NA
    10     1     0
    11     0     0
    12    NA    NA
    13    NA    NA
    14     1     0
    15     0     0
    16    NA    NA
```

But if I condition on the first column only the first column is replaced

```
dplyr::mutate_all(mytbl, funs(replace(., a != 0, NA)))

    # A tibble: 16 × 2
           a     b
       <dbl> <dbl>
    1     NA     1
    2     NA     0
    3      0     0
    4     NA     1
    5     NA     1
    6     NA     0
    7      0     0
    8     NA     1
    9     NA     1
    10    NA     0
    11     0     0
    12    NA     1
    13    NA     1
    14    NA     0
    15     0     0
    16    NA     1
```

I am sure that I am doing something wrong in my approach and I could certainly do this a non-dplyr way, but it seems like this should work. You can extend this with more columns for a similar result.

Comment: That looks strange.  Try with `if_else` i.e. `mytbl %>% mutate_all(funs(if_else(a!=0, ., NA_real_)))`

Comment: That is, indeed, really weird. `ifelse` does not have this behavior, so if you just want it to work, @akrun has you covered. However, the behavior is really odd. If I use `select` to reverse the column order, the error reverses, so, it is a problem with the column ordering. If I use `mutate_each( ..., everything() )`, I get the same problem, but if I use `mutate_each( ..., b)` it correctly assigns the `NA`s in column `b`. I wish I had a better answer for you, but I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think (but have no proof ;)) this is because `a` gets altered and then the condition is re-checked. So when you do

```
dplyr::mutate_all(mytbl, funs(replace(., a != 0, NA)))
```

`a` gets mutated (so it no longer contains non-zero values) - then the condition `a != 0` is re-evaluated but never returns `TRUE`. If you changed this to e.g.

```
dplyr::mutate_all(mytbl, funs(replace(., a > 0, 10)))
```

it would give the desired behaviour. You can try

```
dplyr::mutate_all(mytbl, funs(replace(., mytbl$a != 0, NA)))
```

which won't update the column `a` "on the fly" so will give the desired result.